# At which point in the lifecycle is the "stack" of a Java Thread created and destroyed?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am considering extending java.util.Timer, and completely overriding all public methods, to use a different implementation. The one "problem" I see is, that Timer instantiate and starts a Thread in it's constructor, which I cannot use, due to it being "private". So I would like to not waste the "resources" used up by that Thread. I see at least one things I could do, which is to call super.cancel() directly in the sub-class constructor, thereby immediately closing the thread.

My question is: When are the "resources" of a java.lang.Thread allocated and released?

Allocation: At instance instantiation, or at call of start()?
Release: At "end of run()" or at instance GC time?

If it's JVM implementation specific, I'd like to know how the Oracle JVM does it?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you instantiate an object you allocate space in memory for it. This is the case when you create a `Thread` object as well. It is making perfect sense, as you might wonder how can you use an object which is not stored in the memory. A `Thread` object does not use a lot of memory though. On the other hand, when you call the `start()` method the `run()` method of the Runnable is called and all the resources associated to the `Thread` will be allocated there. If the `Thread` is no longer running, then all the otherwise unreferenced resources used by the `Thread` will be de-allocated by the `garbage collector` eventually. So, if you ask me I think your approach to stop the `Thread` is good, this way only the `Thread` object will remain in the memory along with any other resources you reference.

Comment: You do not address the core of my question; I only care about the *stack* of a thread, which uses a separate memory area *outside the heap* (where the Thread object itself is located). Your answer seems to imply you think the stack is located in the heap; it's not. See this article, for example: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076971/java-concurrency/how-the-java-virtual-machine-performs-thread-synchronization.html